# Как убрать из списка выдачи ls специальные символы точки и двоеточия?

Tags: bash, консоль, список

При работе с терминалом использую для вывода списка каталогов команду `ls -1aR`, получается примерно так:

```bsh
.:
? .
? ..
? 1.txt

./test:
? .
? ..

./tmp:
? .
? ..
? sub
```

Как убрать из списка строки со специальными обозначениями `«.», «..»`?

Comment: вот так ```ls -1AR```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В мануале есть про опцию - "почти всё":

> -A, --almost-all
>                **do not list implied . and ..**

и так будет работаь:

```
$ ls -1AR
```